# Algorithm for drawing the horizon given the current coordinates, elevation and field of view

Tags: algorithms

I have a large database containing coordinates along with an elevation number.
If I am a person looking in some direction (0-360) with an n degree field of view, and located at some coordinate and at some elevation, how can I generate an image representing the horizon? What algorithm should I use?

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  Are you going to generate a horizon once?  Or are you going to do it many times?  Are you interested in solutions that do some precomputation to make each subsequent computation faster?  Possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_(graphics), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm

Comment: @D.W. Hi and thanks! :) I want to create a mobile app (Android) that will generate the horizon many times. It should generate the horizon depending on your coordinates and where you point the camera. Will eventually attempt to match the horizon with what the camera views, and attempt to place the names of peaks that you see in nature, on the display (AR).